# StreamBuilder não retorna valor - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firestore

Olá!

Estou tentando retornar valores de localização com `StreamBuilder`, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

No debug, ele nem chega a executar o builder. Não consigo encontrar o problema.

**Aqui crio o StreamBuilder, para trazer a localização**

```
 _newMoveToApoio(String uidProp) {
    StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('tracker')
            .document(uidProp)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return new Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            var trackerDocument = snapshot.data;
            double latitude = trackerDocument['latitude'];
            double longitude = trackerDocument['longitude']; 

            _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom: 18.0)));
            setState(() {
              _markers.add(
                Marker(
                  draggable: false,
                  markerId: MarkerId("1"),
                  position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: "João Marcelo", snippet: "Sua Localização Atual"),
                  icon: _markerIconApoio,
                ),
              );
            });
          }
        });
  }
```

**Aqui faço a chamada em um bottomsheet, passando o 'uid'**

```
onTap: () =>  _newMoveToApoio(snapshot.data[index].data['uidProp']),
```

Comment: A sua função ```_newMoveToApoio``` não retorna nada? É isso mesmo? Só roda o construtor do StreamBuilder e não usa esse objeto pra nada? Além disso, o que você gostaria que fosse feito com esse onTap? Só chamar essa função assim não vai fazer nada mesmo. Não consegui entender sua intenção.

Comment: @Naslausky Eu não estava usando o StreamBuilder da forma correta. Em um outro canal de duvidas, a pessoa conseguiu me apontar a maneira correta. Vou colocar a resposta aqui para ajudar outros com a mesma dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

Estou respondendo para poder ajudar outras pessoas.
Essa foi a solução encontrada.

```
_newMoveToApoio(String uidProp) async {
  var snapshot = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('tracker')
            .document(uidProp)
            .get();
  // Codigo aqui
}
```